# For Mackenzie, what is the self? What role does the imagination play in forming/defining/altering the self?

Tags: self

I'm having trouble answering this question. The relevant reading is “IMAGINING ONESELF OTHERWISE” by Catriona Mackenzie.

Comment: Hello : it would help if you pointed out specific difficulties you have with the questions.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Phil.SE! I've seen you posted several questions that are too broad and without any background. I'd advise you to put a little bit of effort into the questions you are asking, otherwise they'd be quickly closed and you won't get the answers you're looking for.